# Is there a way to use STL iterators as arguments without a template?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, virtual-functions

I have a `class A` that implements a function `foo` which takes as arguments two iterators (from any stl container). For what I've seen, the common approach is to use a template, as shown here:

```
class A{
    public:
        template <typename It>
        void foo(const It& begin, const It& end){
            // do stuff
        }
};
```

The problem is that I want to make `foo` virtual, and [templates may not be virtual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28009476/error-templates-may-not-be-virtual), but I **don't want to have a class template** like this:

```
template <typename It>
class A{
    public:
        void foo(const It& begin, const It& end){
            // do stuff
        }
};
```

because that would limit the use of `foo` in a single object to one kind of container.

*My question*: is there a way to use STL iterators as arguments without using templates, so that is possible to make such functions virtual and keep it working with any STL container?

**Edit**

Maybe this is a XY problem as said in the comments, so I'm going to explain the specific problem to see what you think.

I have an abstract class called `LightSource` with a pure virtual function `void castLight(...) = 0`. There are two classes that inherit from it and that implement the function, `RadialLight` and `DirectedLight`.

The problem is that to cast light I need a collection of objects `Edge` that specify segments in a 2D world, that may cast shadow. For the algorithm in `castLight` I need to iterate through that collection (not necessarily all of it) and do certain processing that is different in each kind of light.

Comment: There are some ugly workarounds, although this smells of an XY problem.  Templates are a form of compile-time polymorphism.  Virtual functions are runtime polymorphism.

Comment: Perhaps you could ask how to solve the problem that you think requires virtual template functions?

Comment: @fabian That looks like a good approach, but I'm not sure it works for this case. I'm going to edit the question to be more specific with the problem

Comment: What is the collection? You should be able to use: void foo(std::vector<LightSource*>::const_iterator begin, ... if you want to "restrict" to iterators to specific collection. Note: you don't want const before the iterator, you most likely want const_iterator.

Comment: @Zlatomir I'll take that into account, thanks. I guess that I will have to restrict the iterators to certain collection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a specific iterator type, such as `std::vector<int>::iterator`. Note that this may be different to `std::vector<int>::const_iterator`, `std::deque<int>::iterator` and `std::vector<unsigned>::iterator`, so you can end up with a multitude of overloads.

You can also use a type-erasing iterator, such as the iterators from [`boost::any_range`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/any_range.html), or `any_range` itself.

Comment: So the only way is restricting the type of the container and overloading... Well, thank you!